# What book is this passage from?

Tags: mandarin, resources, reading

[image]

I found this passage on 北京大学's website but I can't even go back to the page of contents. I want to know the name of the book。it's the 阅读 section of the site.

Comment: It's an interesting story for me, what's the link of that?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.purpleculture.net/chinese-course-learn-mandarin-grade-1-set-3-vol-2-p-20401/

对外汉语本科系列教材

一年級教材

汉语教程

第三冊

下

Chinese Course - Learn Mandarin Grade 1 Set 3 Vol 2)

[image]

> 第九十一课 Lesson 91
>
> 一、课文: 妻子的秘密

Comment: "Purple Culture"? Same as in "purple passage", defined as "a piece of obtrusively ornate writing"? Interesting.